# How do I get back the option string using argparse?

Tags: python, popen, argparse

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", "--pattern", help="Pattern file")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now is it possible to get back the string `"--pattern"` from `args`?
I need the string so that I can construct a cmd list to pass to Popen like `Popen(['some_other_program', args.pattern.option_string, args.pattern], ...)` without repeating it (and having to maintain it in two places) (`Popen(['some_other_prog', '--pattern', args.pattern], ...)`).

I need to create a wrapper for another program. Some of the args need to be passed to the wrapped program (via Popen) and some are required by the wrapper.

---

Is there a better method than the following example?

```
pass_1 = '--to-be-passed'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", pass_1, help="Pass me on")
parser.add_argument("-k", "--arg-for-wrapper")
args = parser.parse_args()

...
process = Popen(['wrapped_program', pass_1, args.pass_1], ...)
...
```

This method of keeping the args in variables is not very good as:

1. Maintaining short options along with long options becomes difficult.
2. `Popen` if called in another function requires passing these variables(or a dict of them) to the function. This seems redundant as `args` passed to it should be sufficient.

Comment: Why don't you just store it in a variable? ``pattern_str = '--pattern'``, then ``..add_argument(... pattern_str ...)``. There - only one maintenance point.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to hardcode a dependency between two separate programs (and inflexibly so: "these programs must share option names"). Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, the python program is a wrapper for another program.

Comment: Agreed that @AmiTavory 's solution is the only one that's maintainable the way you're trying to do it. Maybe one global dict that has all the patterns as keys and their option flags as values, along with copious amounts of commenting showing why these are pulled out into a global

Comment: @AmiTavory The argparser parses two types of args - those specific to the python wrapper and those to be passed to Popen. Having variables (for args to be passed to Popen) and not for those specific to the wrapper seems a bit messy, though it's a much better option. I'm just asking if there is a better method.

Answer (score 4):

Add a `dest` to your `add_argument` call.

```
parser.add_argmument("p", "--pattern", dest="pattern", help="your help text")
args = parser.parse_args()
args = vars(args)
```

The you can reference the pattern with `args["pattern"]` .

Comment: `argparse` deduces that the dest is `pattern` from `--pattern`.  So the added 'dest' is not necessary.  `args` is a Namespace object, not a dictionary.  `vars(args)` produces a dictionary from it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He's asking how he can have, e.g., `--some-opt` defined in only one place but you have not indicated how to get the string `--some-opt`  back out of the parser.

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to get the original option strings from the result of a `parser.parse_args()`, but you can get them from the `parser` object. You just need to peek into its `__dict__`, in order to retrieve the `parser` settings after it's created. In your case you want the `_option_string_actions` field. Unfortunately this doesn't seem officially supported, as I couldn't find a `ArgumentParser` method dedicated to this, so YMMV. On Python 3:

Demo:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', '-f', type=int, default=1000, help='intensity of bar')
parser.add_argument('--bar', '-b', type=str, default='bla', help='whatever')
store_action_dict=vars(parser)['_option_string_actions']
print(store_action_dict.keys())    # dict_keys(['--help', '-b', '-f', '-h', '--foo', '--bar'])
```

Comment: Variables with leading under-bar are said to be not exposed. So  `_option_string_actions` is meant to be private variable and can change at any time.  So personally I would avoid this type of coding

Answer (score 1):

The deleted answers and comments indicate there is some confusion as to what you want.  So I'll add to that confusion.

Normally the parser does not record the option string.  However it is provided to the `Action` `__call__` method.  So a custom Action class could save it.   The `FooAction` custom class example in the argparse docs illustrates this.

If I define this action subclass:

```
In [324]: class PassThru(argparse._StoreAction):
def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
    setattr(namespace, self.dest, [values, option_string])

In [324]: p.add_argument('-o','--other',action=PassThru)
```

The option string is recorded along with the value ('-o' or '--other'):

```
In [322]: p.parse_args('-p test -o teseting'.split())
Out[322]: Namespace(other=['teseting', '-o'], pass_me_on='test')

In [323]: p.parse_args('-p test --other teseting'.split())
Out[323]: Namespace(other=['teseting', '--other'], pass_me_on='test')
```

Obviously the option_string and value could be recorded in a different order, in a dictionary, as seperate attributes in the Namespace, etc.

---

There are other ways of passing options to another program, particularly if the wrapping parser does not need to handle them itself.

`argparse` gets the arguments from `sys.argv[1:]`, and does not change it.  So even if your parser uses some of the arguments, you could pass that list on to `popen` (all or in part).

The argparse docs has an example, under `nargs=REMAINDER`, of parsing some arguments for itself, and collecting the rest to pass to another program.  This is their example:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
>>> parser.add_argument('command')
>>> parser.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
>>> print(parser.parse_args('--foo B cmd --arg1 XX ZZ'.split()))
Namespace(args=['--arg1', 'XX', 'ZZ'], command='cmd', foo='B')
```

So you could call `popen` with something like

```
plist = ['wrapped_program']
plist.extend(args.args)
popen(plist, ...)
```

Using `parse.parse_known_args` can also be used to collect unparsed words into an 'extras' list.  That section of the docs talks about passing those strings on to another program (just as you are doing).  In contrast with the REMAINDER case, the extra stuff does not have to be last.

These work, of course, only if this parser doesn't need `--pattern` for itself.  If it parses it, then it won't appear appear in the REMAINDER or extras.  In that case you will have to add it back to the list that you give `popen`

I would tweak your parser thus:

```
pass_1 = 'passed'  # without the -- or internal -
dpass_` = '--'+pass_
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", dpass_1, help="Pass me on")
parser.add_argument("-k", "--arg-for-wrapper")
args = parser.parse_args()
process = Popen(['wrapped_program', dpass_1, getattr(args, pass_1)], ...)
```

another option:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
pass_action = parser.add_argument("-p", '--pass-me-on', help="Pass me on")
parser.add_argument("-k", "--arg-for-wrapper")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

If you print `pass_action` (in a shell) you'll get something like:

```
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['-p', '--pass-me-on'], dest='pass_me_on', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

So you could pull the `--name` and `dest` from that object, thus:

```
process = Popen(['wrapped_program', pass_action.option_strings[-1], getattr(args, pass_action.dest), ...], ...)
```

You have to look in `sys.argv` to see which option_string was used (the long, short or other).  The parser does not record that anywhere.

Note '--pass-me-on' produced `dest='pass_me_on'`.  The conversion of `-` to `_` can complicate deriving one string from the other.

If you have a `dest` string, you have to use `getattr` to pull it from the args namespace, or use `vars(args)[dest]` (dictionary access).

Another issue.  If `--patten` has `nargs='+', its value will be a list, as opposed to a string.  You'd have to careful when merging that into the`popen` argument list.